# Why I don't see the volumetrics in eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I have a very strange question:I don't see any squares near the volumetrics bar in Eevee in 2.8.What can I do to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to BSE. Could you explain a bit more what the problem is? You'd like to have a "square" for volumetrics in the setting, but what do you expect if had one?

Comment: Hi,I'm working with smoke simulation right now and as I know to see It in render I need to turn on volumetrics,but I can't, because I don't see anything what can help me.

Comment: You just need to feed volume part of material output and that should work without other settings.

Comment: Thank you,I will try